# VBA form - Returning a textbox object to be manipulated

Tags: forms, vba

I'm creating a game in a vba form.  Right now it creates an array 9x9 of textboxes and fills and disables the textboxes with the given information for the game.  When creating the textboxes I named them "fieldx-y" so I could look them up easily.  I want to somehow put them into an array so that I can look them up like field(x,y) and then do things to them like change the background color of the textbox or change information in it.

Here is the function I wanted to use to find the object using its name and return it to be manipulated.

```
Public Function getField(x As Integer, y As Integer) As MSForms.TextBox
    Dim field As MSForms.TextBox
    For Each field In Me.Controls
        If Right(field.Name, 1) = y And Left(Right(field.Name, 3), 1) = x Then
            getField = field
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

And here is how I would like to manipulate it from my userform initialize sub

```
getField(5,5).Enabled=False
```

I'm sure I must be doing something very wrong and it's probably because of my lacking understanding of OOP and vba.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have chosen a predictable naming convention you can call these controls directly using your naming convention. There is no need to loop through all the controls. Also, I changed your `fieldx-y` to `fieldx_y` because `-` is an illegal character variable names.

```
Public Function getField(x As Integer, y As Integer) As MSForms.TextBox
    set getField = me.controls("field" & x & "_" & y)
End Function
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do in a roundabout way.  My function was missing 'set' as well.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is enabling the control, then you may not actually need to return the textbox, in which case do not add the `tb` variable to the calling procedure, and  change your function to a sub, like:

```
Public Sub getField(x As Integer, y As Integer)
    Dim field As MSForms.TextBox
    For Each field In Me.Controls
        If Right(field.Name, 1) = y And Left(Right(field.Name, 3), 1) = x Then
            '## Disable this textbox
            field.Enabled = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

If you **do** need to return a textbox to the calling procedure, then do this:

In your calling procedure, you need an object variable to represent the returned MSForms.TextBox:

```
Dim tb as MSForms.TextBox
Set tb = getField(5,5)
tb.Enabled = False
```

Then in your function routine, because it is an object, you need the `Set` keyword:

```
Set getField = field
Exit For '## You need to escape the loop otherwise it will keep going, giving undesired results.
```